# Not outputting data after passing props in Link React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is part of my code:

```
<Link to={{pathname:'`/search/${linkurl}/${e._id}`',state:{name:"sumit"}}}></Link>

 <BrowserRouter>
            
      <Route exact path="/search/:searchitm/:buyitem" component={Buypage} />   
      <Route exact path="/search/:searchitm" component={Searchitm} />   
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
              
 </BrowserRouter>   

 console.log(props.location)
```

And this is the output I get:

```
{pathname: "/search/HomeAppliances/c", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined}
hash: ""
pathname: "/search/HomeAppliances/c"
search: ""
state: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Where is my data that I have sent by Link?

Answer (score 1):

if you want pass data with Link use this way:

```
<Link to={{ 
 pathname: "/home", 
 state: { name:"sumit" }
}}>
 Register
</Link>
```

and for get data on the page that navigated to use this:
**props.location.state**

Comment: could you share more data?